# Integrate expression

Tags: integration

Anyone help me to integrate below expression

$$5 x (1 + x ^ 2)^{1/2}$$

the answer I have with as below

$$\frac{5}{3}(1+x^2)^{3/2}+C$$

Comment: You can always differentiate to check. The usual way to integrate is to let $u=1+x^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=1+x^2$ therefore $$\frac{du}{dx}=2x \therefore dx=\frac{du}{dx}.$$ Rewriting the integral, $$\int5x(1+x^2)^{1/2}dx=\int5x(u)^{1/2}\cdot\frac{du}{2x}$$ $$=\frac{5}{2}\int u^{1/2}du$$ $$=\frac{5}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{3}(u)^{3/2}+c$$ $$=\frac{5}{3}(x^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}+c.$$ So your answer is correct.

Comment: I guess you meant $dx=\frac{du}{2x}$ instead of $dx=\frac{du}{dx}$

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to look out for in integration is when both a function and its derivative occur in the integrand. So with your example one sees that we have $1+x^2$
and its derivative is $2x$, the $2$ is not important it is just a constant we can remove it from the integral, but the $x$ is present, this usually means that substitution is the way to proceed, as is now carried out in the other answer.